# Accidentally deleted gnome keyring from startup applications. How do I get it back?

Tags: ssh, startup, startup-applications, gnome-keyring, undelete

I was trying to delete Microsoft teams from the list of startup applications but I accidentally deleted something else from the list instead.

I think that the program I deleted from the list was SSH Key Agent - Gnome Keyring. I think this because of this website:

https://www.maketecheasier.com/manage-startup-applications-ubuntu/

In which there's a picture of the list of what seem to be the default startup programs.

I only just installed Ubuntu. My only remaining startup programs in the list are: "im-launch" and "NVIDIA X Server Settings". Did I in fact delete the Gnome Keyring? How do I get it back? When I press 'add' on the list of startup programs, it expects me to provide it with the location of the program that I want to run, but I don't know where the Gnome Keyring program is in the computer. I tried searching for it in usr/bin, but there are a few different files it could be.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use the command `history` to see your last 1000 shell commands used, in order. Copy/paste the relevant section of that list into your question. We need to see *exactly* what you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"SSH Key Agent" is autostarted by default in an Ubuntu desktop. Therefore, a `.desktop` launcher is installed in `/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop`. Such entries are disabled on a per user basis through settings in a copy in your local autostart folder. To enable the item again, delete your local user copy `~/.config/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop`. To see it appear, you need to quit and restart "Startup Applications" or "Gnome Tweaks" if you used the latter.

Comment: Thanks, it reappeared in the startup applications list.